# Cannot find download link for IBM Connections 4 Fix Pack: 4.0.0.0-IC-Multi-TDISOL-CR2-LO72170

Tags: ibm-connections

I'm following an Install Guide to IBM Connections 4.0. This guide and many others point to the following Cumulative Release 2 Fix Pack:

**4.0.0.0-IC-Multi-TDISOL-CR2-LO72170**

All my online searches have failed me and keep referencing a different fix pack part of a later cumulative release.

This is the only fix pack I'm missing for the full IBM Connections 4 Installation.

Please can someone assist me in finding a download link to this Fix Pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CR3 is released.  You should try that instead.
http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/doSelectFixes?options.selectedFixes=4.0.0.0-IC-Multi-TDISOL-CR3-LO73535&continue=1

TDISOL is just the method to load the users/sync users.

Note, I had issues with CR2, and used CR1 as a fix. CR3 is an option that should work in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Connections 4.0 CR4 is also available; this could be used instead of both CR2 and CR3

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21637538